# Why is await part not getting executed when using async/await with MERN stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I have been follwing a video course for building an app using MongoDb,Express, React and Node (MERN) stack. In the video he has used async/await to connect to MongoDB and for other queries, but the same doesn't work for me. On debug I discovered that the code after await is not getting executed.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');

const db = config.get('mongoURI');

const connectDB = async () => {
try {
    await mongoose.connect(db, {
        useUnifiedTopology: true, 
        useNewUrlParser: true, 
        useCreateIndex: true
    });

    console.log("MongoDB connected...");

} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    // Exit process with failure
    process.exit(1);
    }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

Below is the attached error I'm receiving in the terminal.[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmFcj.png)

Comment: the url of you mongodb is correct and given to mongoose.connect beginning with mongodb://?

Comment: I guess you are requiring this module and then calling connectDB(), correct?

Comment: Can you console log the `db` from this line: `const db = config.get('mongoURI');`
I understand some people don't have this configured correctly and so this may be where your problem is starting.

Comment: The url is correct. I can make a connection if I remove the await and add `.catch(() => {})` at the end of `mongoose.connect` line. But then I'm facing the same problems with await later in the program.